# PowerBI: No visuals appear after changing Excel data source file - file identical format

Tags: filter, visualization, refresh, powerbi-desktop, import-from-excel

Could you please help - for an existing report, I simply changed the data source (Excel file). File is identical format/columns etc. I already resolved the import issues (like PBI Changed Data Type, some row data #N/A issues) so data imported correctly. But my charts on all my tabs are blank.

On a lead it's related to filters - I found the filter funnel button top right - so now clicking on it the filter selections appeared (they had been blank previously). Also a green tick appears next to the dataset in the data pane. I then refresh and but visuals still don't appear. I also have 5 tabs of visuals and doing the same on each of them (1) filter selection and (2) green tick appears but no visuals and clicking away from the tab the filter selections and green tick disappears. But no charts - please help. They should just appear automatically. I refreshed also already and still nothing. I am a PBI novice so please give simple steps, thanks

(1) Tried clicking 'filter and slicers affecting this visual' top right
(2) Tried refreshing

Results were:

- List of
  Filters on this visual
  Filters on this page
  appeared
- Green tick appeared next to dataset in right hand side data pane

Refreshed. No visual. Clicking away from each tab, the list of filters + green tick disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In Desktop, checking "Slicers affecting this visual" and clear manually. Hover over the funnel and clear any slicers you see, or set them to current values.